# Redirecting file descriptor with echo

Tags: bash, file-descriptor

Why is

```
echo 'foo' 1>&2 2>/dev/null
```

giving output? `foo` is redirected to file descriptor 2, file descriptor 2 is redirected to `/dev/null`. There should be no output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's about the order of when you do the redirection. When bash sees several redirections it processes them from left to right.

The first redirection of stdout redirects to current value of stderr (tty). When stderr changes to /dev/null, the stdout is still written to stderrs previous output (tty).

Change place on them and it will work.

```
echo 'foo' 2>/dev/null 1>&2
```

For more details, see http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/

Comment: I still fail to see why.

Comment: Together with this explanation, I understand it now: http://www.catonmat.net/blog/bash-one-liners-explained-part-three/

Comment: Great link, I will add it in the post for others to find.